# Linux and Bluetooth Speaker: Need to pair everytime I want to connect, otherwise “Connection reset by peer” error

Tags: linux, bluetooth, pulse-audio, bluez

A week ago the bluetooth connection of my Linux Laptop to my bluetooth speaker (JBL Horizon) changed its behaviour of the last years.

**How I can was used to use my speaker**

Before I connect to it the following way:

- Had to pair only once via

  - Enabling the pairing mode on my speaker and
  - pair it with my laptop with `bluetoothctl`'s `scan on` + `pair <MAC address>`
- Then I connect to it everytime I want to use it with `connect <MAC address>`

**How I can use it now:**

And since a week, I have to pair it everytime from scratch again. After this it works flawlessly, but pair it everytime again and again is quite annoying.

If I don't do that, I get the following error in `bluetoothctl`

```bsh
[bluetooth]# connect 0C:A6:94:9D:0A:74 
Attempting to connect to 0C:A6:94:9D:0A:74
[CHG] Device 0C:A6:94:9D:0A:74 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 0C:A6:94:9D:0A:74 Connected: no
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 0C:A6:94:9D:0A:74 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 0C:A6:94:9D:0A:74 Connected: no
```

and in `journalctl` or `btmon` the following error

```bsh
Aug 23 19:02:16 laptop-name bluetoothd[517]: connect error: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

**My question**:

- Do you know what reason can be and how I can get to bluetooths previous behaviour?
- Does the `Connection reset by peer` error maybe indicate, that another device is trying to connect to my speaker? Or does it maybe indicate, that something on my speaker is broken?
- Or can it be something on my laptops bluetooth devices? I checked all the updated I performed very recently before the BT's behaviour was changed, but all the packages I installed were not related to `bluez`, `pulseaudio`, `linux-kernel`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the problem is more or less resolved.
The last connections to my already paired speaker went fine -- without repairing it first.

What resolved it, I don't exactly know.. but what I did is the following:

- reinstalled bluetooth related packages (no upgrade, the versions were installed already before)

```bsh
[2020-08-23T23:59:35+0200] [ALPM] installed bluez-utils (5.54-2)
[2020-08-23T23:59:35+0200] [ALPM] installed bluez (5.54-2)
[2020-08-23T23:59:35+0200] [ALPM] installed blueman (2.1.3-1)
[2020-08-23T23:59:35+0200] [ALPM] installed pulseaudio-bluetooth (13.0-3)
```

- Upgraded all packages (which i normally do every ~3 days). The package most related to my issue could be the following

```bsh
[2020-08-24T17:57:35+0200] [ALPM] upgraded linux-api-headers (5.6.11-1 -> 5.7-1)
[2020-08-24T17:57:58+0200] [ALPM] upgraded linux (5.8.1.arch1-1 -> 5.8.3.arch1-1)
[2020-08-24T17:58:03+0200] [ALPM] upgraded linux-firmware (20200721.2b823fc-1 -> 20200817.7a30af1-1)
[2020-08-24T17:58:08+0200] [ALPM] upgraded linux-headers (5.8.1.arch1-1 -> 5.8.3.arch1-1)
```

Of course it could still be, that the speaker itself had some BT problem or another device was connecting to it over a week and now stopped (idk if this could cause a issue I had experienced).

I hope, that it now keeps functioning as it's intended!